# Initial spacing issue on javascript text rotator

Tags: javascript, css

I'm not sure if this is classed as a CSS issue or a javascript issue. I have a javascript text rotator which rotates through a list of different possible words in a sentence, swapping out individual words to change what the sentence says.

It works perfectly, apart from when it first loads, where it leaves the space for the other word options, even though they aren't displayed. After it changes the first word change, the spacing is then correct.

The best way to describe it is to show you, please see when the script first loads how the spacing is out on the sentence, and then how it corrects itself after 5 seconds.

```js
/**
 * The new fancy VanillaJS rotaterator
 * @param {string} selector 
 * @param {object} options 
 */
function rotaterator(selector, options) {
    var defaults = {
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        pauseSpeed: 500,
        child: null
    };

    var options = Object.assign(defaults, options);
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var allSpans = [];

    /**
     * Fade all elements of the given array in by setting display and opacity
     * @param {array} arrElements 
     */
    function fadeElementsIn(arrElements) {
        arrElements.forEach(function (e) {
            if (e.style.display === 'none') {
                // if we are setting from none directly to inline, we need a small delay
                e.style.display = 'inline';
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    e.style.opacity = 1;
                }, 10);
            } else
                e.style.opacity = 1;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Hide all previously cached span elements by setting display to none
     */
    function hideAll() {
        allSpans.forEach(function (e) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set initial styles and transition and fade first elements in
     */
    function initialize(onInitialized) {
        var initialFadeIn = [];
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            var spans = item.querySelectorAll('span');
            spans.forEach(function (span) {
                allSpans.push(span);
                span.style.opacity = 0;
                span.style.transition = (options.fadeSpeed / 1000) + 's linear';
            });

            initialFadeIn.push(spans[0]);
        });

        // finally fade the first set of elements in and call the callback
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            fadeElementsIn(initialFadeIn);
            onInitialized();
        }, 10);
    }

    /**
     * Fade the current items out and fade the next items in
     */
    function next() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var toFadeIn = [];

            items.forEach(function (item) {
                var nextIndex;
                for (var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
                    if (item.children[i].style.opacity == 1) {
                        // fade current item out
                        item.children[i].style.opacity = 0;

                        // set next index to fadeIn
                        nextIndex = (i + 1 > item.children.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1);
                    }
                }

                // save the next element to array
                toFadeIn.push(item.children[nextIndex]);
            });

            // wait for fade out transition effect to complete and then fade all new elements in
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                hideAll();
                fadeElementsIn(toFadeIn);

                // after fadeIn transition effect call this method recursive.
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    next();
                }, options.fadeSpeed);
            }, options.fadeSpeed);
        }, options.pauseSpeed);
    }

    initialize(next);
}

ready(function () {
    rotaterator('.rotate', { fadeSpeed: 500, pauseSpeed: 6000 });
});

/**
 * Polyfill for Object.assign
 */
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
        'use strict';
        if (target == null) {
            throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
        }

        target = Object(target);
        for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
            var source = arguments[index];
            if (source != null) {
                for (var key in source) {
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                        target[key] = source[key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    };
}

/**
 * document.ready function without jQuery
 * @param {function} fn 
 */
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading") {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}
```

```css
.rotate {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<h2 class="light content-medium center text-center soft-top--quad">
Join us for a
    <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>relaxed</span>
        <span>wonderful</span>
       <span>crazy</span>
    </div> 
  weekend of
  <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>fun</span>
        <span>games</span>
        <span>laughter</span>
       <span>dancing</span>
     <span>love</span>
  </div> resulting in your
  <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>best</span>
        <span>worst</span>
        <span>most disgusting</span>
    </div>
     <div class="rotate"> 
        <span>memories</span>
        <span>hangover</span>
    </div>
      </h2>
```

I've tried setting the other word options to display none initially but that doesn't help. Can anyone help me please identify why my text rotator is initially leaving the space for words which are not displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `span`s are all visible (just transparent) the first time, you need to hide them correctly (with display none)

You can do so in css:

```
.rotate span + span { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

opacity = 0 won't collapse, it will occupy the space as it should.
 In your initialisation function, just replace this line :

```
span.style.opacity = 0;
```

by

```
span.style.display="none";
```

Answer (score -1):

Its Java script Loading issue. So you have to set inline or css for hide all rotate div instead of set hide property at initial from Java script.